# Admob Ads Implementation

Tags: android, android-studio, admob, banner-ads

i'm developing an android app which contains 6 different activities for user to interact. I want to know that how many number of banner and interstitial ads should i implement in my application? Guide me in this regard.

Comment: That solely depends upon you. Just make sure that you follow all the admob's policy policy and don't ruin user experience.

Comment: i created just 1 banner ad id from admob & want to implement that banner in 6 different places inside my application. i want to know that is this allowed or restricted?

Comment: Yes, you can use but you should consider creating multiple ad placements so that you can have a greater and clearer earnings analytics.

Comment: Thanks i'll check it out for sure.